# Warning: Attempted to present * whose not in the window hierarchy

Tags: view, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene, presentviewcontroller

I have tried to deal with this issue for too long. Please give me any of your thoughts.

I am presenting a View Controller from an SKScene by sending a Local Notification. `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"closeScene" object:nil];`

The notification is handled in the beginning view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{ [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(closeScene) name:@"closeScene" object:Nil];
[super viewDidLoad];}
```

Then:

```
-(void)closeScene {
//Remove the SKView, or present another viewController here.
constructionViewController *view = [[constructionViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"closeScene" object:nil];
```

}

And every time the notification is sent, I get the warning:

```
 Warning: Attempt to present <constructinoViewController: 0x10ae64160> on <constructinoViewController: 0x10ab329d0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Any help would more than appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When is `closeScene` called, exactly - *before* or *after* `viewDidAppear` gets called?

The error you're seeing usually happens when you try to present a view controller before the parent is actually displayed on screen. Typically this is because you've called `presentViewController` before the parent's `viewDidAppear` method has been called.

Try adding a logging statement to `viewDidAppear` and see whether it appears in the logs before or after your 'view is not in the window hierarchy' error. If it appears after you'll know what the problem is, and how to fix it (make sure `presentViewController` is only called after the parent view controller has been displayed). If it's *before* you probably have an altogether different problem...

Comment: So the main scene, (let us call it x) is the first screen. From x, when you press a button, it presents the scene. The scene loads fine, and then when the game is over, closedScene is called from the scene. closedScene is a method found in x. So as far as if the viewDidAppear is being called, it should have been called at the beginning of the app opening, but then I do not believe it gets called again.

Comment: How are you adding the initial view to the view hierarchy - your app has a root view controller?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: How are you creating your view hierarchy on app launch - all iOS apps should have a root view controller, I'm wondering if maybe you don't have one set and that's what's causing the problems here.

Comment: I do not believe I do... how would I go about settings one?

Comment: Actually, I just set the root view controller like this:

Comment: constructinoViewController *loginController=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homestory"]; //or the homeController
    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginController];
    self.window.rootViewController=navController;

Comment: However, it still is having the same issue